# Некорректное чтение бинарных файлов

Tags: c++, qt, fstream

Мне нужно было считать три бинарных файла с заданной структурой. Структуры их таковы:
Файл 1:

```
struct data_star 
{
    long  NSAO;
    long alpha; 
    long beta;
    short ualpha;
    short ubeta;
    unsigned char mv;
    char sp;
};
```

Считывал его так:

```
data_star d;
QVector <data_star> vec;
ifstream in(filename.toUtf8().constData(),ios::binary);
while(in.read((char*)&d,sizeof(data_star)))// считываем в вектор структур
{
    vec.push_back(d);
}
in.close();
```

Cчитался он замечательно, без каких-либо проблем.

Файл 2:

```
struct sector
{
    float alpha_c;
    float beta_c;
    long count_in_sector;
    long shift;
};
```

Считывал так же:

```
sector sectr;
QVector <sector> vec_s;
ifstream in_1("C:\\Users\\Shmeisser\\Documents\\catalog_v2\\catalog\\NEW_642.CAT",ios::binary);
while(in_1.read((char*)&sectr,sizeof(sector)))// считываем каталог в вектор структур
{
    vec_s.push_back(sectr);
}
```

Но здесь читает совсем некорректно, просмотрев в дебаге запись в структуру, заметил, что частично, данные в структуру записываются верно, то есть, допустим, считанная первая строка имела верные значения в первых трех элементах структуры и неверное в четвертом, и т.д.

3 Файл: (состоит из элемента типа short)

```
short num;
QVector<short> new_numn;
ifstream in_2("C:\\Users\\Shmeisser\\Documents\\catalog_v2\\catalog\\NEW_NUMN.CAT",ios::binary);
while(in_2.read((char*)&num,sizeof(short)))// считываем каталог в вектор
{
    new_numn.push_back(num);
}
```

Тут тоже записывается неверно, но частично или полностью сказать уже сложно. Так вот, суть в том, что когда-то эти бинарники точно считывались, правда сишной библиотекой `stdio.h`. Возможно, они побились, когда я переписывал их к себе на флешку, но что-то я в этом сомневаюсь. В общем, хотелось бы уточнить, возможны ещё какие-то варианты почему файлы читаются неверно? (прежде чем я обращусь к тому, кто эти файлы мне давал, не охота выставлять себя идиотом :) ) . И ещё, если что первая и вторая структура выровнены по 1 байту, так что эта причина отпадает.

Comment: Бинарные файлы записывались , через эти структуры (другой программой) ?

Comment: @Yaroslav, скорее да, чем нет. (последнее изменение файла датируется 98 годом, кто знал эту тайну скорее всего уже умер:)) мне был предоставлен readme файл который содержал описание структур по которым эти файлы следует читать (они аналогичны тому, что в коде)

Answer (score 1):

При компилировании программы , компилятор по умолчанию выравнивает структуры и на разных платформах разными компиляторами выравнивание может быть по разному.

```
struct sector
{
  float alpha_c;
  float beta_c;
  long count_in_sector;
  long shift;
};
```

Такая структура может иметь размер и 16 байт и 24 байта.

Но можно попробовать `__atributte__((packed))` он укажет компилятору что не нужно выравнивать структуру

```
struct sector
{
 float alpha_c;
 float beta_c;
 long count_in_sector;
 long shift;
} __atributte__((packed));
```

Comment: я ведь написал, что структуры выровнены. (правда не так, как вы предложили, а с помощью #pragma pack(push,1); #pragma pack(pop)). Да и у меня стоит проверка на их размер.

Comment: тогда можно предположить, что при записи не было выравнивания ,  и изначальная программа записи бинарных файлов , выравнивала данные по своим размерам.

Comment: тоже маловероятно, в readme представлена такая информация https://i.gyazo.com/a42d6f7ac0b86c96345c19122fb4dfb7.png . там явно указаны сдвиги в байтах, ну и вообще,  я был заверен, что сомневатся в нем не приходится. ну, и в таком случае как объяснить ошибку в чтении файла который содержит в себе только данные типа short?

Comment: Мог писать файлы открытые на запись ни как бинарь а как символьный массив. В него тоже можно писать структуру в бинарном виде, но все символы типа 0x0D могли быть автоматически дополнены 0x0A (или наоборот). Возврат каретки, перенос строки. За свою карьеру встречал эту ошибку уже несколько раз.

Comment: В общем, попробовал ради интереса считать силами QDataStream,аналогичная ситуация, затем силами stdio.h, то же самое. Видимо всё-таки проблема в самих бинарниках, но мне было сказано, что эти бинарники совершенно точно считывались библиотекой stdio.h и даже вроде есть в живом состояний исходники программы, которая это делала. Попробую завтра ее заполучить.